# How to capture tFileOutputPositional output in a global variable?

Tags: talend

How can I capture the output of a tFileOutputPositional in a variable? My tFileOutputPositional outputs only one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to put variables fields by fields in global variables. For example :

InputFlow--->tFileOutputPositional-->tJavarow
Then in your tjavarow :

```
globalMap.put("myVariable_01",input_row.Field_01);
globalMap.put("myVariable_02",input_row.Field_02);
```

with Field_01/02 etc the names of fields in your input schema.